# List of free MMOs for Ubuntu

Tags: games

Is there a list of free MMORPG games for Ubuntu somewhere?

I know of Regnum Online. Any others?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Crossfire : http://crossfire.real-time.com/

Runescape Java : http://www.runescape.com/

Eternal Lands : http://www.eternal-lands.com/

PlaneShift : http://www.planeshift.it/

Puzzle Pirates : http://www.puzzlepirates.com/

Daimonin : http://www.daimonin.net/

A Tale in the Desert (not free): http://atitd.com/

Vendetta Online (not free): http://www.vendetta-online.com/

Adellion : http://www.adellion.com/

Second Life : http://www.secondlife.com/

Wurm Online (not free): http://www.wurmonline.com/

WoW, Runes of magic, Battle of immortals and some other play really well in Wine.

Answer (score 4):

How is Ryzom not in this list??

http://www.ryzom.com

Answer (score 2):

here are some links
[list by linux gamers](http://www.wiki4mmo.com/index.php?title=Linux_gamers)
[wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_massively_multiplayer_online_games)

Comment: First links seems out of date